# How to copy another database apps to SDCard

Tags: android, sqlite, developer-tools

I've install an application to my device. But i want to copy that database to SDcard to be used by my apps. I used this code to copy database. But it's failed. And need "su" command

```
public void copydatabase() throws IOException{
    String [] cmd1 = { "su", "cp", "/data/data/com.apps/databases/data01.db", "/mnt/extSdCard/data01.db"};
    Process process = new ProcessBuilder(cmd1).start();
    try {
        process.waitFor();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Any some code to copy that to SDCard without "su" command??

Comment: [Use `getDatabasePath()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getDatabasePath%28java.lang.String%29) and standard Java file I/O, I would imagine, assuming that this is your own app's database that you are copying.

Comment: no, that is my friend's apps. I was asked to develop by my teacher. maybe i can't use getDatabasePath() to do it

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void copyDataBase(Context mActivity) throws IOException {
        InputStream myInput = new FileInputStream(
                new File("/data/data/" + mActivity.getPackageName()
                        + "/databases/" + "xyz.sqlite"));
        File files = new File("/sdcard/files/");
        files.mkdirs();
        String outFileName = "/sdcard/files/xyz.sqlite";
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bufferLength;
        while ((bufferLength = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
        }
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
    }
```

I hope its useful to you...

Comment: Is the code use to copy my own app's database?? can i use it for copying from another apps database?

Comment: how you know what is the name of other app database?

Comment: i know that database name from "Root Explorer". I know, i can copy that manually with this apps. But can i do it (copy database to sdcard) with my apps??

Comment: give me that root exploler code..then i will give you a list of databases and  copy into our sdcard.

Comment: i get Root Explorer from playstore. I just copy database manually to sdcard then copy to the my own app by Root Explorer. So, i want to make apps that can copy a database from other apps to my sdcard.. Can you help me to solve this?